# Maintain SQL Server scripts

Tags: sql-server

Our firm does not have a dedicated DBA employed but does have select developers performing DBA functions. We update our database often during a development cycle and have a release script with the various updates. We keep our db schema and objects in Visual Studio in a Database Project.

However, we often encounter two stumbling block problems that causes time-intensive manual intervention:

- Developers cannot always sync from the Database Project to their local database because if we have added a NOT NULL field to an existing table that contains data then the Deploy process for VS to the db isn't smart enough to automagically insert "test" data just get the field into the table (unless this is a setting someplace?). We would of course follow this up, if possible, with a script to populate the field with real data, but we can't because the deployment fails.
- Sometimes a developer will restore a backup from any past random date. There is no way of knowing exactly which db updates were applied to this database, so they don't know which scripts to start applying. What we do in this case is to check each script, chronologically, to see if the changes from that script have been applied to the database. If so, move on to the next script to run. Repeat.

One method we have discussed is potentially creating a "Database Update Level" table in the database with 1 field, 1 row. It would maintain the level that the database has been updated through. For example, when the first script is run, update the level to 2. In each db script, we would wrap the statements in a check such as

IF Database_Update_Level < 2 THEN
  do some things here

UPDATE Database_Update_Level SET Database_Update_Level = 2
END IF

The db scripts can then be run on any database because the individual statement won't execute below a certain level.

This feels like we're missing something because this must be a common problem that every development shop that allows developers to develop locally encounters.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

about the restore problem, I don't see many solutions, you might try to prevent full restore and run scripts to populate the tables instead. As for versioning structures, do you use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) in VS ? You can generate DACPACs and generate diff scripts.

But what you say is that you also alter structures directly in the database ? No way to avoid that ? If not you could for example use DDL triggers (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) to at least get notified that something changed.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to solve the NOT NULL problem is to establish default constraints (could just be an empty string, max number value for the data type, max date value, etc.).  When the publish occurs the new column will be populated with the default value.

For the second issue I'd utilize post-deploy scripts in your SSDT project to keep the data in sync utilizing 'NOT EXISTS' to make incremental changes. That way, you can simply publish the database and allow the data updates to occur one after another.